# List of future to single future

Tags: scala, future

Is there a way to convert `List[Future[Seq[Int]]]` to a single `Future[Seq[Int]]`?

I tried `flatten` but that converts it to `Future[List[Future[Seq[Int]]]`.

Comment: Take a look at Future.sequence

Comment: Future.sequence(x).map(_.flatten)

Comment: Thank you for the super quick response!